# Can I set priorities for DB operations?

Tags: android, database

In my android application the user creates certain item at a "Create Item" page, and when they hit Done, I let them continue using the application.

In the meanwhile, in a sequence of asynctasks I do the following DB operations:

- insert the item in the database
- insert the item photos in the database
- insert the item in an upload queue in db
- if internet, read the item from db and upload it to server
- if success, update item with server id in db
- if success, update item's photos with server ids and urls in db
- if success, remove the item from upload queue from db

This takes 2-10 seconds and while these operations are running, the user tries to open the "My Items" screen or "My profile"

Problem is that both screens read information from DB before loading.

Forementioned operations are running in background but DB is inaccessible for "My Items" to obtain items or "My Profile" to obtain items from the DB.

What can I do?

The easiest solution would be to show a loader while those operations are running and make the user wait, which could take a while, especially when uploading images and network is mobile.

**EDIT: Can I set priorities for DB operations?**

Comment: Are you using Transactions?

Comment: Yes I am using transactions whenever possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cleanest way would be a change in your architecture. Instead of using several AsyncTasks you could create a Service which queues the users requests and manage them. You could even split up the service into two. One, which updates the local DB from User input and a second service for syncing with the remote server (consider using a SyncAdapter here). That way the Loaders only need to load a little data. If the operation from the services complete you can use the notification mechanisms to update the loaders. That's the way they are meant to be used.

Basically your actions which will take place before showing something to the user should be as fast as possible. Consider executing long running operations only once and in some other place.

Building an efficient Android Architecture requires some overhead, but if you want to build a top-notch app, there is no way around it.

Here are some additional pointers:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE
Virgil Dobjanschi discusses "Android REST client applications" at the 2010 Google I/O.
The chapter about Architectures for robust Networking in "Enterprise Android" is based upon talk. The book also provides some sample code: http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Enterprise-Android-Programming-Android-Database-Applications-for-the-Enterprise.productCd-1118183495,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html
which might help as a starting point.

DISCLAIMER: I am in no way affiliated with the authors or the publisher

Comment: I have never used loaders nor services, can you show me an example code or a project?

Comment: the services are also going to use the DB in the same time user clicks a screen that also needs it, I dont understand how the situation will improve

Comment: I have implemented a queue only in the cases where internet connection is not available at the time. but if there is an internet connection, im uploading to server right away

Comment: i have edited my answer and included some links which might be helpful. Building good architectures for android is a very complex topic

Answer (score 1):

Can you profile the BLOB write to your database - I assume it's that operation locking the DB for extended periods? Is it worth storing that image in BLOB, or can you just write it to disk and keep a file path reference to it in your DB?

Assuming you can get the DB to at least allow you to read while doing the upload (seems weird it's locking entirely that long):
If you let the user keep using the app, while the image hasn't upload, couldn't you just mark that item as "incomplete sync" (or some kind of wording like that) in the DB, and when the user is going to "My Items" or whatever screen needs items from that DB, show them that the item isn't complete by greying it out with a loading spinner, or something. Like Instagram does while you're uploading a picture.

// edit for misreading what was actually locking

Comment: UI is not locked, but DB is locked. And when DB is locked, users are unable to open certain screens which use information from the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Simply upload one at a time and use optimistic locking for the db update

Comment: as you can see, all 7 operations are related to one item :( what is "optimistic" locking for the db?

Comment: optimistic locking doesn't use transactions for everything.  You query database and if it hasn't changed you update it possibly with a transaction around the update.  What your doing with the transaction around everything is pessimistic locking.  db 101 good luck

Answer (score 1):

Create cache. put every thing into it and let your "My Items" and "My profile" read from it.if you have changed anything or updating any values from your database update your caches if your activities need them. I do not know exactly the dependency of your data but I think it will work in any situations.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you wrap your DB in [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) which has a [applyBatch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#applyBatch(java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.content.ContentProviderOperation%3E)) method supporting sending a list of operations ([ContentProviderOperation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProviderOperation.html)) to perform to your DB (insert/update/delete etc). I then would suggest you to listen with a [ContentObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html) in your "My Items" screen or "My profile" on the provider URI for the different DB updated to be performed and update the screens when a change occurs (cache the values to not have to redraw all the time).